# Is $f_n(x)=\frac {2nx}{1+n^2x^2}$ uniformly convergent?

Tags: calculus, uniform-convergence

$f_n(x)=\frac {2nx}{1+n^2x^2},  0\leq x \leq1 $

we know $f_n(0)\to 0$  and $f_n(1)\to 0$

and $f'_n(x)=0\to x=\pm\frac1n$

since for x<1/n $f'_n(x)>0$  x=1/n is max. point.

it seems $f_n\to^{uc}0 $ how can we show this? is this enough. if it is, for $x=\frac 1n$ doenst it u.con. to 1 since $f_n(\frac 1n)=1\ne0$?

and how can we choose N such that $n\ge N, \forall\epsilon>0$ and $|f_n(x)-0|<\epsilon$

Comment: not sure what $\rightarrow^{ue}$ is supposed to mean, but you've just shown that it doesn't converge uniformly if that's what you're asking for

Comment: I meant $f_n(x)$ uniformly converges to 0. are you sure that it doesn't u. converge?

Comment: You just pointed out that $f_n(\tfrac{1}{n}) = 1 > 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then, for $\epsilon = \tfrac{1}{2}$, there is no $N$ such that $|f_n(x) - 0| < \epsilon$ for all $x$.

Comment: It doesn't uniformly converge. Observe that it converges to $0$ pointwise. Now choose $\epsilon = 1/2$. Is there a $N$ such that if $n>N$ then for every $x$ we have$|f_n(x) - 0|<\epsilon$? Whatever $N$ you try, you won't. Show it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For uniform convergence, it is necessary that $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sup_{0\leq x \leq 1}|f_n(x)|=0$$

As you showed, $f_n$ has a maximum at $x = \frac1{n}$ and $f_n(\frac1{n}) = 1$ for all $n$. Therefore, the supremum is always $1$ and the convergence is not uniform.